# Why does my shortcut try to run an msi, instead of the correct exe

Tags: visual-studio-2008, deployment, windows-installer, clickonce, shortcut

I've created a "Setup and Deployment" project in Visual Studio 2008, and set it to create a shortcut to my application. I tried running the MSI locally and it all worked fine.

I then deployed my app onto a server using ClickOnce. The shortcut was created, however when I click it, it gives some strange errors.

So, when I was just expecting my app to launch, I got the following errors...

[image]

Is this a bug with ClickOnce or is there something I've set up wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Installer shortcuts are one of the entrypoints to the resiliency/repair features, and that's what you've got. If you or your app removed anything that was installed by MSI you'll see this repair going on.

The Application Event log should have an MSI installer log entry that says something about what's wrong, but if you deleted any files or registry entries that the MSI created then that'll be the reason.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've looked in the event log, and I can see a warning. It claims a required resource does not exist. This resource is in fact a zip file, which has been extracted and then deleted. If I put it back the shortcuts runs fine. Go figure.

Answer (score 1):

The MSI is being authored with an advertised shortcut.  The shortcut points to an API that performs a health check (resiliency) before calling the EXE.   See [Troubleshooting unwanted self-repairs using the Event Viewer](http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=HOWTO5638) for more information.

Comment: Seriously appreciate your guidance here. Wish I could accept both answers.

Comment: Well, I did answer first. :)

Comment: Chris knows his stuff, no argument there. Actually think I beat you by 30 seconds :)

Comment: Well, it's a compliment to come in 2nd place to Phil Wilson.